# Writing a thread that stays alive

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, condition-variable

I would like to write a class that wraps around std::thread and behaves like a std::thread but without actually allocating a thread every time I need to process something async. The reason is that I need to use multi threading in a context where I'm not allow to dynamically allocate and I also don't want to have the overhead of creating a std::thread.

Instead, I want a thread to run in a loop and wait until it can start processing. The client calls `invoke` which wakes up the thread. The Thread locks a mutex, does it's processing and falls asleep again. A function `join` behaves like std::thread::join by locking until the thread frees the lock (i.e. falls asleep again).

I think I got the class to run but because of a general lack of experience in multi threading, I would like to ask if anybody can spot race conditions or if the approach I used is considered "good style". For example, I'm not sure if temporary locking the mutex is a decent way to "join" the thread.

**EDIT**
I found another race condition: when calling `join` directly after `invoke`, there is no reason the thread already locked the mutex and thus locks the caller of `join` until the thread goes to sleep. To prevent this, I had to add a check for the invoke counter.

**Header**

```
#pragma once

#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>

class PersistentThread
{
public:
    PersistentThread();
    ~PersistentThread();

    // set function to invoke
    // locks if thread is currently processing _func
    void set(const std::function<void()> &f);

    // wakes the thread up to process _func and fall asleep again
    // locks if thread is currently processing _func
    void invoke();

    // mimics std::thread::join
    // locks until the thread is finished with it's loop
    void join();

private:

    // intern thread loop
    void loop(bool *initialized);

private:

    bool                            _shutdownRequested{ false };

    std::mutex                      _mutex;

    std::unique_ptr<std::thread>    _thread;
    std::condition_variable         _cond;

    std::function<void()>           _func{ nullptr };
};
```

**Source File**

```
#include "PersistentThread.h"

    PersistentThread::PersistentThread()
{
    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(_mutex);
    bool initialized = false;

    _thread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(&PersistentThread::loop, this, &initialized);

    // wait until _thread notifies, check bool initialized to prevent spurious wakeups
    _cond.wait(lock, [&] {return initialized; });
}

PersistentThread::~PersistentThread()
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        _func = nullptr; 
        _shutdownRequested = true;

        // wake up and let join
        _cond.notify_one();
    }

    // join thread, 
    if (_thread->joinable())
    {
        _thread->join();
    }   
}

void PersistentThread::set(const std::function<void()>& f)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    this->_func = f;
}

void PersistentThread::invoke()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    _cond.notify_one();
}

void PersistentThread::join()
{
    bool joined = false;
    while (!joined)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        joined = (_invokeCounter == 0);
    }   
}

    void PersistentThread::loop(bool *initialized)
{

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    *initialized = true;
    _cond.notify_one();

    while (true)
    {       
        // wait until we get the mutex again
        _cond.wait(lock, [this] {return _shutdownRequested || (this->_invokeCounter > 0); });

        // shut down if requested
        if (_shutdownRequested) return;

        // process
        if (_func) _func();
        _invokeCounter--;

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)

Comment: Maybe this should be posted on Codereview SE ?

Comment: @NathanOliver I second that. Just create a few threads all at once right at the start, then use them.

Comment: I agree with @NathanOliver http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency might come in handy

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych would it be a good idea to split the question in question and (my own) answer then? I couldn't find anything against a question like this in the how-to

Comment: @ruhigbrauner I mean if you have a working code and you just need a review to encounter some issues or improve something - there is a site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych  Didn't knew about that forum. ;) Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about potential race conditions, and I see at least one race condition in the shown code.

After constructing a `PersistentThread`, there is no guarantee that the new thread will acquire its initial lock in its `loop()` before the main execution thread returns from the constructor and enters `invoke()`. It is possible that the main execution thread enters `invoke()` immediately after the constructor is complete, ends up notifying nobody, since the internal execution thread hasn't locked the mutex yet. As such, this `invoke()` will not result in any processing taking place.

You need to synchronize the completion of the constructor with the execution thread's initial lock acquisition.

EDIT: your revision looks right; but I also spotted another race condition.

As [documented in the description of wait()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), `wait()` may wake up "spuriously". Just because `wait()` returned, doesn't mean that some other thread has entered `invoke()`.

You need a counter, in addition to everything else, with `invoke()` incrementing the counter, and the execution thread executing its assigned duties only when the counter is greater than zero, decrementing it. This will guard against spurious wake-ups.

I would also have the execution thread check the counter **before entering `wait()`**, and enter `wait()` only if it is 0. Otherwise, it decrements the counter, executes its function, and loops back.

This should plug up all the potential race conditions in this area.

P.S. The spurious wake-up also applies to the initial notification, in your correction, that the execution thread has entered the loop. You'll need to do something similar for that situation, too.

Comment: Would a solution be to add a `auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(_mutex);` before creating the thread, add `_cond.wait(lock);` after the creation and then let the thread call `_cond.notify_one();` after the local lock was created? I can also edit the source in the question,...

Comment: Added what I assume is a solution in the source

Comment: Ok, catching spurious wakes is an issue. But since "invoke" blocks , could multiple `invoke` calls pile up? I.e. If the thread is processing, a different thread can't invoke. Even with a spurious wakeup, the thread gets the lock ad thus while handling the wakeup, a diferent thread can't call invoke (or at least is blocked as long as thread is not waiting). Am I missing something?

Comment: The counter-based solution should fix that too.

Comment: Follow-Up, Quote from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait:
 "It may also be unblocked spuriously. When unblocked, regardless of the reason, lock is reacquired and wait exits."

Does that mean that when two threads work with one mutex and one awakes from wait, he "steals" the lock from the other thread?

Comment: Made some adjustments to ctor and loop

Comment: No, the awakened thread does not "steal" the lock. The awakened thread is blocked until it can acquire the lock after the other thread releases the lock.

Comment: I found another race condition: calling `join` directly after `invoke` might be faster then the wake up and thus might get the lock faster then the thread, returning before the thread evens tarted processing. :'D

I added a "busy loop" that might help but also tested another approach using a `_cond.wait()` inside `join()`(combined with checking `if (_invokeCounter > 0)`. 
Does the edited  version in the question create any problem?

Comment: I would change ` if (_shutdownRequested) return;` to  `if (_invokeCounter == 0) return`. Since the only alternative to `_invokeCounter` being zero, at this point, is `_shutdownRequested` being set. So if a race condition ends up incrementing the counter and setting the flag, the code will first handle all the invocations, before terminating.

Comment: But since the `if (_invokeCounter == 0)` check is used to prevent invalid wake ups, the scenario can't happen, right?

Comment: It will certainly happen if `_shutdownRequested` was set, and the condition variable notified.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to ask exactly. It's a nice style you used.

It would be much safer using `bools` and check the single `routines` because `void` returns nothing so you could be maybe stuck caused by bugs. Check everything you can since the thread runs under the hood. Make sure the calls are running correctly, if the process had really success. Also you could read some stuff about "Thread Pooling".

Comment: Are you talking about using bools as a result type for `_func`? I'm not quite sure where this would prevent problematic scenarios. I feel like catching exceptions would hep but that's about it.

Comment: Catching exception would be the same sense at the end, just more expensive

Comment: @Lazcano Exceptions are zero-cost when they don't occour. When they do, however, they're much more expensive but it shouldn't really matter since it's something you don't expect to happen very often in most cases.